# How to encrypt a password with bcrypt in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

Good Morning
I have a problem with bcrypt for incrypt passwords in node js
my comparison variable returns false
My code to insert my password (motDePasse in French) in my db

```js
// con.escapeId(sorter);
  //ICI CRYPTAGE DE motDePasse bcrypt 
  motDePasse =  bcrypt.hashSync(motDePasse, 10);
  //var sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `first_name`,`last_name`,`telephone`,`user_name`,`password`,`adresseMail`,`rue`,`codePostal`,`ville`,`confirmation`) VALUES (NULL, '"+con.escapeId(nom)+"','"+con.escapeId(prenom)+"','"+con.escapeId(telephone)+"','"+con.escapeId(pseudo)+"','"+con.escapeId(motDePasse)+"','"+con.escapeId(adresseMail)+"','"+con.escapeId(rue)+"','"+con.escapeId(codePostal)+"','"+con.escapeId(ville)+"','"+confirmation+"')";
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `first_name`,`last_name`,`telephone`,`user_name`,`password`,`adresseMail`,`rue`,`codePostal`,`ville`,`confirmation`) VALUES (NULL, '"+nom+"','"+prenom+"','"+telephone+"','"+pseudo+"','"+motDePasse+"','"+adresseMail+"','"+rue+"','"+codePostal+"','"+ville+"','"+confirmation+"')";

  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
```

and my code to select the password

```js
con.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='"+login+"'" , function (err, result) {
    //con.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='"+login+"' and password = '"+password+"'" , function (err, result) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    
    const comparison =  bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password);
    console.log("comparison:"+comparison);
```

The const comparison return false I don't understand why
Thanks for your help :)
I have followed your good advices
Here my new code

```js
/ICI CRYPTAGE DE motDePasse bcrypt 
   bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {//---
           bcrypt.hash(motDePasse, salt, function(err, hash) {
           console.log("hash:"+hash);
           
           
  
  
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `first_name`,`last_name`,`telephone`,`user_name`,`password`,`adresseMail`,`rue`,`codePostal`,`ville`,`confirmation`) VALUES (NULL, '"+nom+"','"+prenom+"','"+telephone+"','"+pseudo+"','"+hash+"','"+adresseMail+"','"+rue+"','"+codePostal+"','"+ville+"','"+confirmation+"')";
```

```js
con.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`= ?" ,[login], function (err,result) {
    //con.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='"+login+"' and password = '"+password+"'" , function (err, result) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("password:"+password);
    bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, function(err, result) {
            console.log("result:"+result);
           });
```

When I past my hash in my code directly it's working Result is true
The problem is coming from Mysql
thanks for your help
The probleme came from

```js
let motDePasse=req.body.motDePasse.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

I delete that and all is fine thanks for your help :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `...Sync` functions in a request handler. It will block your server.

Comment: ```"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='"+login+"'"``` is open to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements, never concatenate variables into SQL strings by hand.

Comment: Some more details: https://openbase.com/js/bcrypt/documentation#sync _"Why is async mode recommended over sync mode?

If you are using bcrypt on a simple script, using the sync mode is perfectly fine. However, if you are using bcrypt on a server, the async mode is recommended. This is because the hashing done by bcrypt is CPU intensive, so the sync version will block the event loop and prevent your application from servicing any other inbound requests or events. The async version uses a thread pool which does not block the main event loop."_

Comment: The first parameter in bcrypt.compareSync() the password isn't declared anywhere in your sample code. Maybe it is declared further up as a global or closure var? Still, this need to be eliminated as the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your help the problem is resolved :)